# Unresponsive landlord not providing lease renewal

Tags: united-states, rental-property

I am renting an apartment (not rent-controlled) and my lease will be up at the end of the month. My current lease states the landlord is supposed to provide the renewal lease at least 60 days before the end of the current lease. There are 16 days until the end of the lease and I have not received the lease renewal.

I have tried emailing and calling the landlord multiple times over the last several weeks (leaving voice messages). I did once manage to reach them a couple of weeks ago and they said they would get it to me.

I have tried contacting them since for an update, but have not heard from them. Aside from any legal action I might be able to take against them, what should I do in the meantime if my lease ends and they so not respond? Should I attempt to send rent?

Comment: In the jurisdictions I'm familiar with, the landlord's failure to provide a lease renewal causes your tenancy to convert into a month-to-month tenancy with terms governed by state law.

Comment: Do you want to continue your tenancy, or do you wish to leave?

Comment: I would prefer to continue the tenancy. Aside from issues with the landlord, there are a lot of perks to the current location.